# Racket simple sequence of int generator function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I have started working on my first racket function but there is a big problem.

```
(define (sequence low hide stride)
   (letrec ([list-of-int null])
          (define (f low hide stride)
           (if (< low hide)
              [(begin ((append (list low) list-of-int)
                (f (+ low stride) hide stride)))]
              [list-of-int]))
     (f low hide stride)))
```

Can anybody help me with my racket understanding? In my mind it looks fine but doesn't work. I have found more simple solution in internet:

```
(define (sequence low high stride)
   (if (> low high)
     null
     (cons low  (sequence (+ low stride) high stride))))
```

I understand it but why my code doesn't work? Can anybody help me?

Oscars answer is really great) Thanks a lot dear friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this function already exists in Racket, and it's called [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29):

```
(range 1 11 1)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Now, regarding your implementation you have to remember that list operations in Scheme do *not* modify lists in-place. In particular, this line is not doing what you imagine:

```
(append (list low) list-of-int)
```

Sure enough, `append` added a new element, but it returned a new list, and because you didn't store it as a variable or passed it as a parameter that modification was lost. Besides, it's better to use `cons` to build an output list, using `append` will result in a quadratic performance. Also, there's a mistake in here:

```
[(begin ((
```

See those double `[(` and `((` there? they' re causing the `"application: not a procedure"` error being reported. In Scheme, surrounding an expression with `()` means *function application* - parentheses are *not* to be used for defining blocks of code, as you would use `{}` in other programming languages. A correct implementation from scratch follows, closer to what you had in mind and preserving the same behavior as `range`:

```
(define (sequence low high stride)
  (define (f low cmp acc)    ; lower bound, comparator and accumulator
    (if (cmp high low)       ; exit condition for base case
        (reverse acc)        ; reverse and return the accumulator
        (f (+ low stride)    ; advance lower bound
           cmp               ; pass the comparator
           (cons low acc)))) ; build the list
  (if (positive? stride)     ; if the step is positive
      (f low <= '())         ; initialize with <= comparator and '()
      (f low >= '())))       ; else initialize with >= and '()
```

It works as expected:

```
(sequence 1 11 1)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

(sequence 1 12 2)
=> '(1 3 5 7 9 11)

(sequence 10 0 -1)
=> '(10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are so mach mistakes in small piece of code. It is really cool answer.

Comment: looks like I am an idiot but in my racket repl it doesn't work...I don't understand anything...

Comment: @РоманИванов What's the error reported? make sure that the first line in the file says `#lang racket`, and that the language selected in the options is "determine language from source".

Comment: All fine for now - thats help)